# Bluetooth multiple connection j2me

Tags: java, java-me, bluetooth

If i found RemoteDevice and ServiceRecord in my client(functions deviceDiscovered, servicesDiscovered). Then open connection with found serviceRecord(e.g. stream = (StreamConnection) Connector.open(url);). Then close this connection. And again create connetion with found service. If two of my clients will work at the same time, you get a "multi-connection"?(The first client connected worked, the second waits. And vice versa.)
What is the limit on the number of bluetooth connections? At the level of search device, service or other?

Answer (score 0):

You can find out using `System.getProperty("bluetooth.connected.devices.max")`; see [here](http://java.sun.com/javame/technology/msa/jsr82.jsp) for descriptions of this and other system properties related to JSR 82.